# Boolean for "not not True or False and not True"

Tags: boolean

what is the boolean result for

> not not True or False and not True.

I thought it is False, but the answer is True.

Comment: If you already know the answer, why are you asking? If you want an *explanation* of how to *simplify* this expression, SO might not be the right place to be asking.

Comment: not not True is True, anything after the OR is irrelevant

Comment: Add information about the language this is in, otherwise the operator precedence is not defined!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really about precedence: `not` has higher precedence than `or` so `not not True` is evaluated first, as `True`. Next, `and` has higher precedence than `or`, so the second clause can be taken all together but does not need to be evaluated because `True or (anything)` is `True`.

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever points out, not all languages have the same precedence rules (for example, Smalltalk evaluates expressions strictly left-to-right.

Comment: In any sane language, yes, `not` will have a higher precedence than `or`. You answer also presumes that `and` has a higher precedence than `or`. But there could be esoteric languages with different precedence rules. Operator precedence is by no means universally defined. If `or` were evaluated before `and`, then the final comparison would be `(anything) and False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
not not true or false and not true
|
v
not false or (false and not true)
|
v
true or (...)
|
v
true
```